# Centos 6.2 Openwebmail change password issue

Tags: openldap, pam

Recently build environment to test, install openldap, openwebmail and PAM authentication module 
After experiencing the current account login webmail change password will be "password is wrong, change unsuccessful.."

openwebmail.log display

```
Fri Mar 21 16:50:40 2014 - [2543] (192.168.126.1) testuser - change password error - auth_pam.pl, ret -4, pam_authtok() err 10, User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

Current settings

/etc/httpd/conf.d/openwebmail.conf

```
auth_module auth_pam.pl
```

/etc/pam.d/openwebmail

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       sufficient   /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so
auth       required   /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so
account    required   /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so
account    sufficient     /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so
password   sufficient  /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so
password   required    /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so
```

Did not know where the setting is wrong cause this problem?